# Allowing client domain to point to my domain

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, plesk, vhosts

I'm currently using Plesk which is running a nodejs app. I'd like to enable users to point their domains at mine eg:

```
client.clientsite.com -> client.mysite.com
```

My extra nginx file looks like so:

```
server_name *.mysite.com;
location ~ / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

I've tried:

```
server_name _;
```

But this does not work, this also breaks the subdomains for mysite.com. It does kind of work with:

```
server_name *.clientsite.com *.mysite.com
```

But this would not be a viable option as the website grows. The *.clientsite.com also ends up showing [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) instead of client.mysite.com

The SSL is all setup via cloudflare and works fine, its just this nginx problem which I cannot get my head around.

Thanks